# Using Jooq as a SQL Builder

Tags: jooq

I have a question regarding license for JOOQ being used as a sql builder with AWS RDS being the underlying database.
Can the ASL 2.0 be used or Jooq license is required?

Thanks,
Kanika

Answer (score 0):

Per jOOQ 3.13, there is no separate licensing option for AWS RDS. If you’re planning to use jOOQ with MariaDB, MySQL, or PostgreSQL on AWS RDS, the ASL 2.0 licensed jOOQ Open Source Edition will suffice. If you’re planning to use jOOQ with Aurora, Oracle, or SQL Server on AWS RDS, the jOOQ Professional Edition will be needed.

See the [jOOQ database support website](https://www.jooq.org/download/#databases) for an up-to-date list of supported database products per jOOQ edition and distribution.